# How to print randomized text in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I'm writing a "card game" in which every time I press a button it's supposed to output a random "card" or text. The thing is, it "works" but not really how it should, by that I mean that when I press the button, it outputs a random text, but it outputs just that specific text. It doesn't randomize the value AFTER I run the program and I press the button.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Label, Text
import os
import random

cards = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
value=random.choice(cards)

def printcard():
    print(value)


root = tk.Tk()

Title = Label(root, font="Times 20 bold", 
fg="#242424", text="This is A title")
Title.pack()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=529, width=640, bg="#242424")
canvas.pack()

theframe = tk.Frame(canvas, bg="#dbdbdb")
theframe.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.62, relx=0.1, rely=0.2)

Cardcontent = Label(theframe, font="Times 20 bold", bg="#dbdbdb",
fg="#242424", text="This is a card")
Cardcontent.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.62, relx=0.1, rely=0.17)

Newcard = tk.Button(root, text="New Card", padx=10, pady=5, 
fg="#dbdbdb", bg="#242424", command=printcard)
Newcard.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I couldn't find anything similar to this problem in this site nor elsewhere so, I tried moving some lines hoping that changing the hierarchy would solve the problem, but it didn't I want to clarify that this is literally my first time writing code so if you could dumb down any explanations or responses it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you click the button you only call `printcard` which will just print value. You have to reassign value if you want it to pick a new one each time.

```py
def printcard():
    value=random.choice(cards)
    print(value)
```

Comment: OMG Thank you so much Pete, really.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)